# How to permute the shape of a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2-dimensional array generated from a string (call it `matrix`):

```
131 673 234 103 018
201 096 342 965 150
630 803 746 422 111
537 699 497 121 956
805 732 524 037 331
```

When parsed, it becomes the next array of arrays:

```
[
  [131, 673, 234, 103, 018],
  [201, 096, 342, 965, 150],
  [630, 803, 746, 422, 111],
  [537, 699, 497, 121, 956],
  [805, 732, 524, 037, 331]
]
```

However, I need to manipulate this so that the array is instead like this one:

```
[
  [131],
  [201,673],
  [630,096,234],
  [537,803,342,103],
  [805,699,746,965,018],
  [732,497,422,150],
  [524,121,111],
  [037,956],
  [331]
]
```

This array is a `2-dimensional` array created by following the `up-left` diagonals of the string or current array.

I think that the string could be manipulated (perhaps into one line) and rebuilt with newlines in the correct position for my current code to work, however I just cannot think of how to implement this.

To create the array I am using this code:

```
matrix.split("\n").reduce((a, b) =>
{
    a.push(b.split(" ").map(x => parseInt(x)));
    return a;
}, []);
```

(`matrix` is the name of the variable holding my string)

Preferably, I would be able to just replace my reducer function, however any solution would be of great benefit to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your approach, I have done some modifications to push every item of the inner arrays on the corresponding diagonal. I have use [Array::unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to insert at the beginning of a diagonal array when we push a new element.

```js
const matrix = "131 673 234 103 018\n201 096 342 965 150\n630 803 746 422 111\n537 699 497 121 956\n805 732 524 037 331";

let res = matrix.split("\n").reduce((acc, curr, idx1) =>
{
    curr.split(" ").forEach((n, idx2) =>
    {
        // Calculate idx of the diagonal this item belongs.
        let dIdx = idx2 + idx1;

        // Insert element on the related diagonal.
        acc[dIdx] = acc[dIdx] || [];
        acc[dIdx].unshift(parseInt(n));
    });

    return acc;

}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go from the left side first and then at the bottom from left to right and take the diagonal values of the array

```js
function getDiagonal(x, y) {
    var result = [];
    while (x >= 0 && y < data[0].length) result.push(data[x--][y++]);
    return result;
}

var data = [[131, 673, 234, 103, 018], [201, 096, 342, 965, 150], [630, 803, 746, 422, 111], [537, 699, 497, 121, 956], [805, 732, 524, 037, 331]],
    result = [],
    i = 0, j = 1;
 
while (i < data.length) result.push(getDiagonal(i++, 0));
while (j < data[0].length) result.push(getDiagonal(data.length - 1, j++));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my shot:

```js
const input = `131 673 234 103 018
201 096 342 965 150
630 803 746 422 111
537 699 497 121 956
805 732 524 037 331`;

let matrix = input.split('\n').map(line => {
  return line.split(' ').map(elem => parseInt(elem.trim()));
});

let rows = matrix.length,
    cols = matrix[0].length,
    numDiags = rows + cols - 1,
    diagLimit = Math.max(matrix.length, matrix[0].length);

let diagMatrix = [...Array(numDiags)].map((_, diagNum) => {
  let diag = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < diagLimit; i++) {
    let r = (diagLimit - 1) - i,
        c = i - (diagLimit - 1) + diagNum;
    
    if (r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < matrix.length && c < matrix[0].length) {
      diag.push(matrix[r][c]);
    }
  }
  
  return diag;
});

console.log(diagMatrix);
```

This iterates through every diagonal of length `max(rows, cols)` which overlaps the matrix, adding elements within the overlap to the output array. It also handles rectangular matrices, so you could make a couple optimisations if you’re only dealing with square ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick that you can use. Here's the layout of the indices of your matrix:

```
00  01  02  03

10  11  12

20  21

30
```

If you notice, the indices of each diagonal add up to the same number, which is the index of the result array.

You can use this information to easily transform your matrix as follows:

```js
const transform = (matrix, rows = matrix.length, cols = matrix[0].length) => {
    const result = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            const k = i + j; // this is the resulting index
            if (k >= result.length) result[k] = []; // create new rows on the fly
            result[k].push(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return result;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(transform([ [131, 673, 234, 103,  18]
                                     , [201,  96, 342, 965, 150]
                                     , [630, 803, 746, 422, 111]
                                     , [537, 699, 497, 121, 956]
                                     , [805, 732, 524,  37, 331]
                                     ])));
```

Hope that helps.